# Page like layout in Tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

Is there any workaround method to make tinymce editor like Google Docs.

Here i want to display the content as page like Google docs.

Please share your thoughts? is that possible ?

http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/5083/docsgooglecomacirclemed.png

Comment: I might be wrong, but I believe Dipen is asking about simulating Microsoft Word's "Print Layout View"

Answer (score 1):

two with examples with boostrap:

http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0DFT966

http://jhollingworth.github.com/bootstrap-wysihtml5/